# Using HTML inside PHP

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array

I know I must be missing something, but I can't seem to echo a PHP variable in HTML.

Here is what I have:

```
$query.= "
    <div id='leftc'>
        <a href='index.php?sid=". $de[2]['sid'] . "'><img src=' " . $de[2]['imgname'] . "' style='height: 128px; width: 128px;'/></a>
    </div>";
```

Waht I get is a link with index.php?sid=

I know I have a value inside

```
$de[2]['sid'] //12
$de[2]['imgname'] //somepic.jpg
```

I have a similar code which works:

```
$query.= "img/Series/" . $series['imgname'] . "'style=\"height: 128px; width:128px;\"/></a> ";
```

Only this, of course is not an array element.

How could I pass the array value

```
$de[2]['sid']
```

inside HTML?

***FROM YOUR COMMENT***

So we can actually read it.

This might be complicated but bear with me: First I construct MySQL query and fetch the results:

```
$dupepisodes = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * 
                                  FROM Episodes, Series 
                                  WHERE Series.id = sid 
                                    AND airdate='{$duplicate['airdate']}'");
```

This particular query searches for duplicate entries. Then:

```
while($dupep = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dupepisodes)) { 
    $de[] = array('sid' => $dupep['sid'], 
                  'imgname' => $dupep['imgname']
                 ); 
}
```

I store the data in `$de[];` Right after I check it:

```
echo $de[2]['sid']; 
echo $de[2]['imgname'];
```

I get the values in browser.

***UPDATE***

Here how it looks now:
[image]

***UPDATE 2***

```
print_r($de);
```

It returs as follows:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [sid] => 12 [imgname] => 5287397.jpg ) 
    [1] => Array ( [sid] => 22 [imgname] => ) 
) 
12225287397.jpg
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [sid] => 12 [imgname] => 5287397.jpg ) 
    [1] => Array ( [sid] => 22 [imgname] => ) 
    [2] => Array ( [sid] => 12 [imgname] => 5287397.jpg ) 
    [3] => Array ( [sid] => 22 [imgname] => ) 
)
```

I know it contains same data but nevertheless I could choose what I need from them.

I have used 
     print_r($de)

BEFORE and AFTER I called it in the query string (same result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I used

```
$de[3][''];
$de[4][''];
```

which were echoed back but never got to html string (still a mystery as to why).

When I switched to

```
$de[0][''];
$de[1][''];
```

suddenly it got to the html string and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work.`query = '<div><a href="index.php?sid='.$de[2]['sid'].'"><img src="'.$de[2]['imgname'].'" style="height: 128px; width: 128px;"/></a></div>';`

Comment: This messed my divs a bit but it still did not work. I will try to play with quotes though.